# Insert rows in sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a sqlite db and i want to insert row in it . I used this code for inserting rows and make a query.

```
   -(void)InsertRecords{

    querySQL1 = @"select category from notes where id=5";
    const char * query_stmt = [querySQL1 UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO notes (id, title, content,dataAdd,category) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\" ,\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                           @"5",
                           @"georgiana",
                           @"20",
                           @"12.09.2019",
                           @"public"];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"data inserted");

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

    }
    }


    else
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));




    querySQL1 = @"select id from notes where category LIKE 'public'";
    query_stmt = [querySQL1 UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

   NSString *idNr=@"";
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        idNr =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:
               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",idNr);

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

Everything is ok, but when I open the app again, I don't find any value for idNr.

Any useful help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe coz your database dsnt have anything with Like public thats why?

Comment: and why it;s nothing like public if i insert it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSString` allocation is wrong statement, There is no need to `alloc` NSString object here.

The method `stringWithUTF8String:` is class method. This will do the allocation for `NSString`.

Replace your code like below:

```
NSString *idNr = @"";
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    idNr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

}
```

Comment: but i have another problem now, when i start again the app , the row inserted is not there .

Comment: The reason behind that is - In application lifecycle some where you overwrite or create new database. So that previous values are not persistence. Check that your database / table is not overwritten or re-created.

Comment: i update my question , please take a look at my code . I dont see where i am wrong .

Comment: First of all - Manually check that record is there in sqlite db or not. You can open database by using this this plugin - [SQLite manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) in Mozilla Firefox browser.